# Set default select text in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm pretty new into angular and already got my first problem. I looked for a solution on stackoverflow but no one got the same scenario as me. I want to set a default text in my "select box". Just something like "Choose your car". But I don't know how to insert this default text. I tried to solve it in the way i learned it in HTML. But it didn't work because I don't have any  tags.

p.s. I also tried a little bit of MVC. I think it isn't correct at all, but ignore it for this post.

That would be my code:

**View** -> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x.marke for x in cars">
    </select>

  <h1>You selected: {{selectedCar.marke}}</h1>
  <h1>The color is: {{selectedCar.farbe}}</h1>
  </div>


<script src="./JS/myApp.js"></script>
<script src="./JS/myCtrl.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Model** -> myApp.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

**Controll** -> myCtrl.js

```
  app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.cars = [
  {marke: "Lamborghini", farbe: "Gelb"},
  {marke: "Bugatti", farbe: "Schwarz"},
  {marke: "BMW", farbe: "Blau"},
  {marke: "VW", farbe: "Grau"}
  ];
  })
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: people already answer...just add your default option manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another option like below,

```
 <select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x.marke for x in cars">
     <option value="">-- Choose your car --</option>
 </select>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.cars = [
  {marke: "Lamborghini", farbe: "Gelb"},
  {marke: "Bugatti", farbe: "Schwarz"},
  {marke: "BMW", farbe: "Blau"},
  {marke: "VW", farbe: "Grau"}
  ];
  })
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x.marke for x in cars">
     <option value="">-- Choose your car --</option>
    </select>

  <h1>You selected: {{selectedCar.marke}}</h1>
  <h1>The color is: {{selectedCar.farbe}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add an default option like so:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x.marke for x in cars">
  <option value="">Please select one</option>
</select>
```